# Using Python to multiply/divide columns in CSV files

Tags: python, csv, multiplication

So I have a number of CSV files with 6 columns of numbers in each file. I would like to perform a few operations (multiplication, division etc.) on each column in each of the CSV files using Python.

```
import csv

r = csv.reader(open('F:\python\sample.csv','rb'))

w = csv.writer(open('F:\python\sample_calib.csv','wb',buffering=0))

for row in r:
            a = (float(row[0])-0.0376)/-0.0717
            b = (float(row[1])-0.0376)/-0.0717
            c = float(row[2])/1000
            d = float(row[3])/1000
            e = float(row[4])/1000000
            f = float(row[5])/0.001178
            w.writerow([a,b,c,d,e,f])
```

So I am using this small script above to calibrate each row and this works fine for each .csv file. Now all I want to do is to run this script for 200 FILES in one folder. Can some one tell me how should I edit the script and what modules to add?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to get familiar with the `csv` module: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: There's a short example on that page: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Comment: I have included the script I am using for each .csv file above in my question. If you could please tell me how to edit the script to run it for 200 files in one folder.

Comment: You'll need the `os` module, especially http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the arrangement and data type of each column, your best bet would be [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) and the [loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) function.

Code to use it would look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
dtype = np.format_parser(['f4', 'f4', 'i4'], ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], [])
array = np.loadtxt(path_to_file, dtype, delimiter=',')
```

Then you can perform operations on an entire column like this.

```
output = array['col1'] + array['col2']
```

The `f4` and `i4` refer to the data type of each column - `f4` is a 32 bit floating point number, and `i4` is a 32 bit integer.  Other options are `i8`, `f8`, or `aN` for 64 bit integer, 64 bit float, and N length string.

One caveat - if your data contains strings which include commas, the loadtxt function doesn't handle them well.  You'll have to use the `csv` module as recommended by other posters in that case.